# Which IDE support LESS (Dynamic Stylesheet Language)?

Tags: ide, less

If someone here knows which IDE support LESS? There are many problems when I'm working on it.

If I make a mistake, the [JavaScript](http://lesscss.org/#download) won't render my LESS CSS; that why I need IDE to correct some of my errors.

Answer (score 1):

[IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), the best IDE in the business, supports LESS CSS with a plugin:

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pr=idea&pluginId=7059

Comment: I'll try to use this IDE for promgramming. anyways, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Scott Guthrie just announced that there is now [first class support for LESS in Visual Studio 2012](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/02/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-update.aspx). 
I haven't tried it, so I'm not sure what "first class support" means.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Linux (Ubuntu) :D

Comment: IntelliJ has a community edition that runs on Linux.  If you're doing web apps, not Java, their WebStorm is based on the same solid technology as IntelliJ.  Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Intellij IDEA with plugin LESS
and another plugin "LESS CSS Compiler"
you can compile CSS in real time
when you edit LESS file ,the CSS is already output.